# Griffon Gsql - how to config datasource in Config.properties file?

Tags: grails, groovy, griffon

griffon gsql plugin's datasource config is write in DataSource.groovy,
and i want it to be in Config.properties, how?
i try, it don't work:

1. add Config.properties at conf

2.config in Config.properties:
dataSource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/smp?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8

3.remove this config from DataSource.groovy

it seems the gsql plugin must to read config from DataSource.groovy.

ps: is gsql plugin opensource?

Comment: What have you tried? What error are you getting? What are you trying to do?

Comment: i try to move dataSource.url ... from DataSource.grooy to Config.properties,but gsql cant work at startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sloved.
ref to http://markmail.org/thread/gslnhxseaicc5ksp#query:+page:1+mid:beunoxesbbmlmznp+state:results

```
//read config.properties http://markmail.org/thread/gslnhxseaicc5ksp#query:+page:1+mid:beunoxesbbmlmznp+state:results
def props = new Properties()
props.load(getClass().classLoader.getResourceAsStream("Config.properties"))
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(props)

dataSource {
    dbCreate = "skip"
    pooled = config.dataSource.pooled as boolean
    //set this to true if using MySQL or any other RDBMS that requires execution of DDL statements on separate calls
    tokenizeddl = config.dataSource.tokenizeddl as boolean

    driverClassName = config.dataSource.driverClassName
    url = config.dataSource.url
    username = config.dataSource.username
    password = config.dataSource.password
}
```

Comment: sigh... so few griffon dp in statckoverflow,and i always answer the question myself....